# What does `standardUserDefaults` on `NSUserDefaults` do?

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I have question related to `NSUserDefaults`'s `standardUserDefaults`.
What exactly does the `standardUserDefaults` method do?
Is it initializing the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes or no. `NSUserDefaults` is a singleton, so there is ever only one instance of the class around, and `standardUserDefaults` is the method to get that single instance.

If there isn't an instance of `NSUserDefaults` yet, it is `alloc`'ed and `init`'ed and then returned, otherwise this already present instance is returned.